# Use List from cshtml.cs in cshtml

Tags: asp.net, razor

I want to use a List from cshtml.cs in my cshtml Page.

I filled my needed stuff in a List in the cshtml.cs programm. now i want to visualize it in the cshtml page.

cshtml.cs

```
public List<Day> Days{ get; set; }
```

cshtml

```
<div class="row recipes">

    @foreach (var Day2 in Days)
    {
    <div class="recipe col-md-4">

        <h3><a>@Day2.Name</a></h3>
        <p>@Day2.Beginn</p>
        <p>@Day2.End</p>

    </div>
    }
</div>
```

Error is "The Name "Days" is in the actuall context not given."

Comment: You don't show how you're planning to get data into your Days property. Have you created a model in your controller, populated it, and passed it into the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have used a viewmodel to send the List data to the view.

the Syntax should look like this:

```
<div class="row recipes">

    @foreach (var Day2 in Model.Days)
    {
    <div class="recipe col-md-4">

        <h3><a>@Day2.Name</a></h3>
        <p>@Day2.Beginn</p>
        <p>@Day2.End</p>

    </div>
    }
</div>
```